# How to create mysql table with two types of index from php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create one mysql table with two index, one is as INDEX and the other is as UNIQUE (on two columns). I can create/modify both of those index directly by entering phpmyadmin at later (after creating table) but can't do that from php by mysql query. I can create only one index from php by mysql query:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
id int(5),
name varchar(150),
address varchar(150),
telephone varchar(11)
UNIQUE INDEX(name,address))
ENGINE=MYISAM
```

I want to create something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
id int(5),
name varchar(150),
address varchar(150),
telephone varchar(11),
INDEX(id),
UNIQUE INDEX(name,address))
ENGINE=MYISAM
```

But How to create both index by the mysql query from php end?

Comment: I don't think you can create a table named `table` - `table1` works here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68def1

Answer (score 0):

You could create the INDEX using a separate statement:

```
CREATE INDEX table_id ON table (id);
```

By the way, in your first statement you're omitting a comma after:

```
telephone varchar(11)
```

Perhaps that's why you were unable to create both indexes.

Comment: Thanks gknicker for your reply. Actually the missing comma was a typing mistake, In actual query, comma is there. So that was not the cause, If I try to create two index together like in my second statement, it is showing "You have an sql error near (before 2nd type of index)".